# Retaining the scrolled position in RecyclerView with scrollToPosition is not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onresume, onpause

I am trying to use onPause and onResume methods to retain the scrolled position of the RecyclerView when an intent is used to launch another activity (a web browser in my case)

The "lastFirstVisiblePosition" is a valid integer when I'm debugging the onResume method, however the screen is still scrolling all the way up to the first element of the RecyclerView.

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

**EDIT: I am using a viewpager and i have multiple recycler views/fragments**

heres my fragment:

```
public class CultureFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<News>>, RecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClicked {
    private String baseUrlString = "https://content.guardianapis.com/search?show-fields=headline,thumbnail,wordcount,trailText";
    private String LOG_TAG = CultureFragment.class.getName();
    public LoaderManager loaderManager;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
    private TextView mEmptyStateTextView;
    private View LoadingIndicator;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private int lastFirstVisiblePosition;

    View rootView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setRetainInstance(true);

        //initialise rootview
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.word_recycler_view, container, false);

        //set up empty text view
        mEmptyStateTextView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        mEmptyStateTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        //Set up loading indicator
        LoadingIndicator = rootView.findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);


        // initialising the recycler view and setting the adapter for adding items.
        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);


        //set the layout manager for item positioning in the list
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        //Setting up loadermanager if there is connection
        if (NewsActivity.isConnected) {
            loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
            loaderManager.initLoader(1, null, this);
        } else {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            LoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mEmptyStateTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mEmptyStateTextView.setText(R.string.no_connection);
        }


        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public Loader<List<News>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        Uri baseUri = Uri.parse(baseUrlString);
        Uri.Builder uriBuilder = baseUri.buildUpon();

        //Create the URL
        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("section", "culture");
        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("page-size", "20");
        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("api-key", "test");
        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("format", "json");
        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("orderBy", "newest");

        Log.e(LOG_TAG, " the url  " + uriBuilder.toString());

        return new NewsLoader(getContext(), uriBuilder.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(android.support.v4.content.Loader<List<News>> loader, List<News> data) {
        //populate the recyclerview
        //dismiss the loading indicator
        LoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (data != null) {
            recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), data);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);


            //set the on click listener if the adapter is not NULL (here)
            recyclerViewAdapter.setOnClick(this);

        } else {

            // Remove recycler view, and set the no text textview
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mEmptyStateTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mEmptyStateTextView.setText(R.string.no_stories);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(android.support.v4.content.Loader<List<News>> loader) {

    }

    /*Custom on item click method, implemented in the recycler view Adapter*/
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        News news = recyclerViewAdapter.getItem(position);

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(news.getmWebUrl()));
        startActivity(i);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        lastFirstVisiblePosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (lastFirstVisiblePosition > 0) {
            ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPosition(lastFirstVisiblePosition);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually what happens is, the recyclerview is scrolling all the way up for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

Use LinearLayoutManager and the 2 methods:

```
 linearLayoutManagerInstance.onSaveInstanceState()
 linearLayoutManagerInstance.onRestoreInstanceState()
```

Comment: Hi Jose, why would the onpause and onrestore not work in this case ?

Comment: You need to use the correct way @tipi linearlayoutmanager has a instance working with onsave and on restore. onPause and onRestore are for all app, not just for recyclerview